# Missing part from a brake pad kit

Tags: brakes

I bought the following brake pad kit

[Wagner ThermoQuiet QC1293 Ceramic Disc Pad Set With Installation Hardware](http://amzn.com/B002WB0M8K)

[image]

I expected the kit comes with all the hardware,

However, the kit is missing the highlighted part in the following diagram:

[image]

I found about the missing part at the middle of the installtion. The older part was so badly rusted and damaged so I just put everything together without the highlighted part.

Question 1: Is that part actually important?

Question 2: If it is important **why** it is missing from such premium kit? If it comes with many pad related installation hardware, why the highlighted part should be missing?

Question 3: Is it so important that I need to buy one and install it? The installed pads seem to be working well.

Answer (score 5):

These appear to be anti-squeal/anti-rattle shims. These are now built into the brake pads instead of coming separately. Don't worry about them.

Comment: On the Wagner ThermoQuiet this is true. Some brands still include the shims and aren't built in.

Comment: @Ben - Thanks for making that distinction ... very true!